# Emacs customizable variable with dynamic set of possible values

Tags: emacs, customization, typechecking

I want to define a customizable variable in Emacs Lisp whose possible values are restricted to a certain list, but the list should be dynamically created by a function each time the user opens the customization buffer. Thus, something similar to

```
(defcustom my-variable
  [...]
  :type '(choice [...])
```

but `choice` seems to support only a static set of values. What I want is something like

```
(defcustom my-variable
  [...]
  :type '(choice my-function)
```

where `my-function` is a function that returns the list of possible values, and is evaluated each time the customization buffer is created.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

```lisp
(defun my-function ()
  "..."
  '(42 "a" b (x y) "c"))

(defcustom foo 42
  "..."
  :group 'convenience
  :type '(restricted-sexp
           :match-alternatives ((lambda (x)
                                  (car (member x (my-function)))))))
```

Function `my-function` could provide a different list of possibilities each time (or whenever, based on whatever).

This simple example doesn't provide much in the way of feedback (and no doc strings).

But the idea is this: `restricted-sexp` is the most general `defstruct` type-defining construct.  This is what the Elisp manual, node [Composite Types](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Composite-Types.html) says:

> `(restricted-sexp :match-alternatives CRITERIA)`
> This is the most general composite type construct.  The value may
> be any Lisp object that satisfies one of `CRITERIA`.  `CRITERIA` should
> be a list, and each element should be one of these possibilities:
>
> - A predicate—that is, a function of one argument that returns
>   either `nil` or non-`nil` according to the argument.  Using a
>   predicate in the list says that objects for which the
>   predicate returns non-`nil` are acceptable.
> - A quoted constant—that is, `'OBJECT`.  This sort of element in
>   the list says that `OBJECT` itself is an acceptable value.
>
>   For example,
>
>   ```
>      (restricted-sexp :match-alternatives
>                       (integerp 't 'nil))
>   ```
>
>   allows integers, `t` and `nil` as legitimate values.
>
>   The customization buffer shows all legitimate values using their
>   read syntax, and the user edits them textually.

In the example I gave, the list of `CRITERIA` is a singleton, with just this function:

```lisp
(lambda (x) (car (member x (my-function))))
```

That function ensures that the value you use for the option is a member of the list that function `my-function` returns.  (And it makes the value be the `car` of what `member` returns, i.e., the particular member of the list that the user enters.

When using `M-x customize-option` you won't be able to **set** a new value if it isn't one of the values returned by `my-function`.
Instead of seeing feedback that the value was set to what you entered, you continue to see this help text:

`EDITED, shown value does not take effect until you set or save it.`

If you provide a valid value then you get confirmation that the value was set.

---

Admittedly, what you might really want is to provide for completion etc. in the editing field.  For that, you would need to use/define an appropriate widget, because Customize, out of the box, provides for completion only for a limited set of `defcustom` type constructs (files, colors, etc.). You can see which ones by searching for `completion` starting in node `Simple Types`.

---

`restricted-sexp` is really a wonderful thing. It should be improved by Emacs to be more useful. But even as it is it should be used more, to provide *more-specific type checking*. Too many users defining `defcustom`s are a bit lazy, IMO, not bothering to provide a specific type definition even when that might be as simple as using `choice`.  (Too many just use a type of `sexp`.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I wasn't aware that `restricted-sexp` is so powerful. However, I opted for a different solution (see my answer below), which has the advantage that the standard `choice' type can be used (no need to define new widgets), so the user can select the value from a nice menu.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: I defined `my-variable` with type `choice` and only one default entry, then I wrote a function that updates the `choice` entries dynamically, and added that function to `'Custom-mode-hook`. This hook is called each time Custom mode is entered. Thus, whenever the user is about to customize `my-variable`, the choice entries are updated before. Here is a sketch of code:

```
(defcustom my-variable
  "None"
  :type '(choice (const :tag "None" "None")))

(defun my-function ()
  ;; Function that provides the possible values of my-variable
  )

(defun my-update-variable-allowed-values ()
  (let* ( (choices '((const :tag "None" "None"))) )
    (dolist (val (my-function))
      (setq choices (cons (list 'const ':tag val val) choices)))
    (setq choices (cons 'choice choices))
    (put 'my-variable 'custom-type choices)))

(add-hook 'Custom-mode-hook 'my-update-variable-allowed-values)
```